# switching button texts by using toggle states

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When clicking on a button, this button should change its text. The button itself toggles another element.

```js
function switchBtnText(btn, contentElement, contentText) {
  var stateText = contentElement.is(":hidden") ? "hide" : "show";
  contentText += " <b>" + stateText + "</b>";
  $(btn).html(contentText);
}

function toggleOne() {
  $("#p1").slideToggle();
  switchBtnText($("#btn1"), $("#p1"), "Text 1");
}

function toggleTwo() {
  $("#p2").slideToggle();
  switchBtnText($("#btn2"), $("#p2"), "Text 2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" onclick="toggleOne()">Text 1 <b>hide</b></button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="toggleTwo()">Text 2 <b>hide</b></button>

<p id="p1">Text _ 1 _</p>
<p id="p2">Text _ 2 _</p>
```

So the first click on the button is fine. The button switches its text to "show". But when clicking agai (the element is shown) it does not switch back to the "hide" text.

I use `contentElement.is(":hidden")` to check if the element is hidden or shwon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `.is(":hidden")` before you use `.slideToggle()`

```
function toggleOne() {
  var isVisible = $("#p1").is(":hidden");
  $("#p1").slideToggle();
  switchBtnText($("#btn1"), isVisible, "Text 1");
}
```

```js
function switchBtnText(btn, isVisible, contentText) {
  var stateText = isVisible ? "hide" : "show";
  contentText += " <b>" + stateText + "</b>";
  $(btn).html(contentText);
}

function toggleOne() {
  var isVisible = $("#p1").is(":hidden");
  $("#p1").slideToggle();
  switchBtnText($("#btn1"), isVisible, "Text 1");
}

function toggleTwo() {
  var isVisible = $("#p2").is(":hidden");
  $("#p2").slideToggle();
  switchBtnText($("#btn2"), isVisible, "Text 2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" onclick="toggleOne()">Text 1 <b>hide</b></button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="toggleTwo()">Text 2 <b>hide</b></button>

<p id="p1">Text _ 1 _</p>
<p id="p2">Text _ 2 _</p>
```

Comment: ah, didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the `slideToggle` logic to the function `switchBtnText` to avoid repeat that code in all `toggleOne` and `toggleTwo` funcitons...

Than, within function `switchBtnText`, update the `contentText` variable once the `slideToggle` function call is finished

And finally update the button text `$(btn).html(contentText);`

Code:

```js
function switchBtnText(btn, contentElement, contentText) {
  var stateText = contentElement.is(':hidden') ? 'hide' : 'show';
  contentElement.slideToggle(function () {
    contentText += ' <b>' + stateText + '</b>';
    $(btn).html(contentText);    
  });
}

function toggleOne() {
  switchBtnText($('#btn1'), $('#p1'), 'Text 1');
}

function toggleTwo() {
  switchBtnText($('#btn2'), $('#p2'), 'Text 2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" onclick="toggleOne()">Text 1 <b>hide</b></button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="toggleTwo()">Text 2 <b>hide</b></button>

<p id="p1">Text _ 1 _</p>
<p id="p2">Text _ 2 _</p>
```